# Why can't I create copies of these 2D arrays in C?

Tags: c, computer-science, cs50

Hello I am doing an assignment for Harvard CS50 please read the [directions](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2021/psets/4/filter/less/) if you want to answer the question.

Here is my code for `helpers.c`

```
#include "helpers.h"
#include <math.h>

// Convert image to grayscale
void grayscale(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            RGBTRIPLE pixel = image[i][j];

            int newgray = round((pixel.rgbtBlue + pixel.rgbtGreen + pixel.rgbtRed)/ 3.00);
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = newgray;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = newgray;
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = newgray;
        }
    }
    return;
}
// Convert image to sepia
void sepia(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            RGBTRIPLE pixel = image[i][j];

            //Reassign pixel colors based on formula
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = .393 * pixel.rgbtRed + .769 * pixel.rgbtGreen + .189 * pixel.rgbtBlue;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = .349 * pixel.rgbtRed + .686 * pixel.rgbtGreen + .168 * pixel.rgbtBlue;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = .272 * pixel.rgbtRed + .534 * pixel.rgbtGreen + .131 * pixel.rgbtBlue;
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Reflect image horizontally
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width/2; j++)
        {
            temp[i][j] = image[i][j];
            int reflected_j = width - j;
            image[i][reflected_j] = image[i][j];
            image[i][j] = temp[i][j];
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    return;
}
```

**My first question** is why is it that when I replace `image[i][j].rgbtBlue = newgray;` in the *grayscale* function with `pixel.rgbtBlue = newgray;` it doesn't work. Isn't the pixel variable literally a copy of `image[i][j]`.

**My second question** lies in the *reflection* function where I make `RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];` (RGBTRIPLE is a data structure using 1 byte for each RGB color in the images picture) and assign it to copy the pixels of the original image. I made it so that it would copy the first half of the picture and reflect it to the other side from the original image then from the copy (`temp`) I would copy the second half and paste it in the first half of the original image. Why does the first half (left half) come up as black?

Input: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxn2T.png), *terminal command*: `./filter -r tower.bmp outfile.bmp`
(tower.bmp is the input image and outfile is the output image)

Output: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wObC1.png)

Comment: "Isn't the pixel variable literally a copy of image[i][j]". No, it is a copy of the value of image[i][j]. Modifying pixel won't modify image[i][j]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value) (Specifically the 2nd answer there)

Comment: If the pixels come black, it is because they are getting set to 0 (atleast, that's the standard)

Comment: You dont need an entire array for temp. Just use one variable.

Comment: Are you sure that C has 2D arrays? Last time I read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) it did not have them (just arrays of arrays)

Comment: `image[i][j].rgbtRed = .393 * pixel.rgbtRed + .769 * pixel.rgbtGreen + .189 * pixel.rgbtBlue;` is suspicious as `.393 * pixel.rgbtRed + .769 * pixel.rgbtGreen + .189 * pixel.rgbtBlue;` may exceed 255.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your first question, it is because pixel is only a value copy of image[i][j]. It has a separate memory location of it's own, so modifying it wont change the image[i][j].
As for your second question it is because this line

```
image[i][reflected_j] = image[i][j];
```

should be

```
image[i][j]=image[i][reflected_j]
```

and this line

```
image[i][j] = temp[i][j];
```

should be

```
image[i][reflected_j]=temp[i][j]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with `reflect()`.

1. Only one element of `temp` is used at a time and never reused. Thus there is no need to create a potentially huge instance on stack.
2. Index `reflected_j = width - j` for `j` equal to 0 will be equal `width` what is out of bounds for array of length `width`. This invokes *UB*. It should be `reflected_j = width - j - 1`
3. It would be better to **swap** pixels while reflecting the image, not to play with half-copy.

Updated code:

```
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]) {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int i = 0, j = width - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
            RGBTRIPLE temp = image[y][i];
            image[y][i] = image[y][j];
            image[y][j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```